# Get data from another UWP application

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I wan't to access data stored in another UWP application. I saw that you can save data in the `LocalState` folder of your UWP application using this code :

```cs
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("longtime");

StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("example.txt",
                         CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, formatter.Format(DateTime.Now));
```

[Here is the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

So with this code I create a file called example.txt in my first UWP project.

Is it possible to get access to the example.txt from a second UWP project ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible only if both apps are published by same publisher.

This folder cache is called `PublisherCacheFolder`

Here is a [Blog Post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/#gZI2mgDuSbGgvP58.97)   that will explain this in detail.

You need to Add an extension in your appmanifest before this can be done in all the apps that you prefer to share data.

```
<Extensions>  
  <Extension Category="windows.publisherCacheFolders">  
    <PublisherCacheFolders>  
      <Folder Name="Downloads" />  
    </PublisherCacheFolders>  
  </Extension>  
</Extensions>
```

There is a good video explaining about this on [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P495)  . Jump to 19th Minute.

Below are simple Write and Read Methods from another [Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashish/2015/05/20/windows-10-app-to-app-communication-in-universal-windows-applications/).

```
async void WritetoPublisherFolder(string Text)  
{  
    StorageFolder SharedFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("CommonFolder");  
    StorageFile newFile = await SharedFolder.CreateFileAsync("SharedFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);  
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(newFile, Text);  
}  

async Task<string> ReadFromSharedFolder()  
{  
    StorageFolder SharedFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("CommonFolder");  
    StorageFile newFile = await SharedFolder.GetFileAsync("SharedFile.txt");  
    var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(newFile);  
    return text;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I'm looking for !

Answer (score 2):

Applications in UWP are sandboxed, thus you cannot so easily access their storage. There are couple of options for sharing data:

- you can use [KnownFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries) which can be accessed by any app with suitable capabilities,
- you can [use picker to save a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-save-a-file-with-a-picker) in user chosen location,
- you can [use picker to pick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) a folder to which your app will have access,
- or you can just [share data with other apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/), that are registered for receiving specific content.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an AppService which can share any data. Basically the provider will host the service and the app who needs data should consume the service.

More info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service